# Codeigniter Php Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to achieve autocomplete search and I added all necessary jQuery but it still doesn't work.

Here is my View :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#dseancename').autocomplete({
       source:"<?php echo site_url('AddSeance/search/?'); ?>"

   });
});
```

And my Controller:

```
function search() {
  $this->load->model('SalonModel');
if(isset($_GET['term'])){
$result = $this->SalonModel->search($_GET['term']);
if(count($result) >0){
    foreach ($result as $pr)
        $arr_result[] = $pr->name;
    echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
}}
```

And my Model :

```
 function search($name) {

    $this->db->like('name',$name,'both');
    return $this->db->get('seance')->result();//table name seance
}
```

I tried to make it an array and it works. But I can't make it with database values. I searched on the internet and find someone who already did it but it doesn't work to.

Comment: Are you sure your controller method executed?

Comment: I don't know how can i make sure ? but in my view:source  it looks <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#dseancename').autocomplete({
           source:"http://localhost/ci_project/AddSeance/search/?"
           
       });
    });
</script>

Comment: You make sure this by using debugger. BTW,  try to remove `?` at end of url at view.

Comment: i remove it but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your modelview you can make a search.

```
 public function search($name)
{    
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE row LIKE ('$name%')");
if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
          {
         $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['tablename']));
          }
         echo json_encode($row_set); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: you can use this link => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811301/autocomplete-in-codeigniter?rq=1